# PC froze midgame and now turns on then off right away

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, freeze

Was playing a game and it froze completely. As in the mouse and everything was frozen. Turned it off and let it sit for a few minutes and tried turning it on. It turns on for 1 sec and then turns back off. It will keep trying to boot up if i don't turn off the psu. I built the PC about a year and a half ago and just the other day I changed cases. Everything has been working great before that.

Checked for any loose cables first and none are loose. Removed and put the ram back in and no change. I've never had an issue like this so not sure what the best order would be for this.

If it matters the specs are:
MSI sli 270z MB,
i7 7700k,
GTX 1080 Strix,
2x 8GB G.skill ram,
Bronze 650w PSU

Nothing is overclocked and the temps previously were 54 celsius during gaming.

Any help is appreciated =) Thanks!

Comment: Ok so I unplugged the gpu, harddrive, and ram and it booted up. Found out its the 4th slot for the ram. It boots on with the ram in the 1st and 3rd slot but no video. The gpu has rgb and usually go through all the colors during bootup but now its going between orange and white and no video on screen. Would this be a MB issue or something else?

Comment: More information.. Found out the cpu cooler was loose. Tightened that up in hopes of it maybe helping the motherboard if it was warping and it did nothing. There was also some slight residue on the motherboard. It feels like moisture.. or oil or something. It was on the back of it by the CPU.

Comment: Another update. As I wanted a new mobo anyways i decided to get one. Now it's worse. No matter the configuration of the ram it wont boot for more than half a second.

Comment: Took out the cpu.. boots up.. so what causes a i7 7700k to fail in a little over a year.. it used to average 70 Celsius in games and recently it was 50s.. I've never overclocked it. Could I of just gotten a bad one or is there something I could of done?

Answer (score 0):

Well i fixed it and im going to keep this question on here incase anyone else has the same problem. Im still not positive if it was the mobo or the cpu but im leaning towards mobo. I bought a z370e which I did not know was not compatible with my 7700k so I was forced to buy a new cpu. Wanted a new one anyways so not a big deal.